# any workarounds to get polymorphic functions in Data.Dynamics?

Tags: haskell, dynamic-typing

The function `dynApply` from `Data.Dynamics` looks very nice, but in reality it requires a monomorphic function type. So, you couldn't write

```
dynApply (toDyn id) (toDyn 3)
```

I have some code that needs polymorphic return types. They are of a restricted form, e.g. functions

```
forall t. (a -> t) -> t
forall t. (a -> t) -> b -> t
forall t. (a -> t) -> b -> c -> t
...
```

(where `a`, `b`, `c` are concrete types). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can the list of possible return types be enumerated (up to the polymorphic `t`, of course)?

Comment: @DanielWagner, that approach might work, thanks, but I think it will be too much effort, considering the range of things [with different instances of _t_] that I'll need to apply them to.

Comment: Also I should point out someone seems to be working on it [ http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PolymorphicDynamic ], but there isn't any resulting code yet.

Comment: Add type annotations to the function to make it look monomorphic? `(id :: Int -> Int)`

Comment: @DanBurton, It's precisely the point not to do so; the type of the argument passed into the function is not known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, polymorphic functions are incompatible with `Data.Dynamic`.  To do this would require a polymorphic `Data.Typeable` and the use of the typechecker at run-time.

There is however, a ticket for this feature: [Polymorphic Data.Dynamic](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4459)